# How do I give access to other users if they don't have SSH keys?

Tags: ssh, hosting, digital-ocean, ssh-keys, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new in setting up a [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) ([DigitalOcean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DigitalOcean) droplets), and the recommendation is to set up an SSH key rather than logging in with username and password. I've successfully added the SSH key to my VPS, but I'm not the only user of this VPS or I will be using another computer. I am not sure if it's a good idea to pass around private keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Others can access the droplet by using the `username/password` of that machine (DigitalOcean droplet).
- Or, you can login from a machine (`SSH already added`). Now add a `new ssh-key` in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file of the DigitalOcean droplet.

There is one default root/password for every droplet. You can reset `root password` using the DigitalOcean GUI (<kbd>Reset Root Password</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for hint. but the machine has no more user/password access is only through ssh

Comment: There is default `root/password`. if you can't know than you can change the password by `admin mail`. Update my answer.

Comment: I see,, I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

> I will be using another computer. I am not sure if it's a good idea to pass around private keys.

No, it is not a good idea to move the keys around (unless they are stored on secure hardware -- HSM). Otherwise it is good practice to create separate keys (encrypted) on the computers you plan to use and add them to the VPS. Then you can simply revoke the one, if they got potentially compromised and avoid exchanging all the keys on all you computers.